# insertBefore throws error in Internet Explorer 11 when trying to change DOM of a popup

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-11

The issue happens in Internet Explorer - 
When I try to change a content of a dom object which is in popup using the insertBefore from the parent container it throws invalid argument error. Below is my popupcontainer and the popup html.

popucontainer.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function changeDomContent(obj) {
            var heading = document.createElement('h2');
            heading.textContent = "Content from parent container";
            obj.insertBefore(heading, obj.firstChild)
        }
        function openPopup() {
            window.open("popup.html", "_blank", "location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,height=500px,width=800px");

        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Parent Container, who will change the dom content of the popup</h1>
    <button onclick="openPopup()">Open Popup</button>
</body>

</html>
```

popup.html -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        function fnInit() {
            var winObj = window.opener;
            winObj.changeDomContent(document.getElementById('appContainer'));
        }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Testing InsertBefore</h1>
    <div id="appContainer">
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="fnInit()">
        Test InsertBefore
    </button>
</body>

</html>
```

Note that I did go about using the outerHTML / innerHTML which works in IE, but this is from KnockOut JS and basically some of the events doesn't get fired if we just change using outerHTML/innerHTML, it expects to be a proper node being inserted.
The above code will work fine in Chrome. Any suggestions would help. Thanks!

Comment: So... what does the error say?

Comment: It says - Invalid Argument